Proof of a Conditional Expectation Result Using Truncation and Conditional Jensen's Inequality
Let $X, Y$ be integrable random variables. If with probability one
$E[X|Y] = Y$ and $E[Y|X] = X$, then $X = Y$ almost surely.
(Hint: first assume $X, Y$ are $\mathbb{L}^2$, and then use truncation and conditional
Jensen’s inequality.)
I can prove it assuming $X, Y \in \mathbb{L}^2$, but I wonder what the rest of the hint means. This result has been proven in various posts in this forum, but none uses the conditional Jensen's inequality.
